# Can I use sql bulk copy to copy data within the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

Can I use sql bulk copy to copy data within the same server ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: we have both 2005 & 2008

Comment: Heloooo...pleaseee...we nee to know this soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, in the demo code shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), they copy to a table within the same database.

Comment: But please keep in mind, that this is not the recommended way, as the article states itself: "If the source and destination tables are in the same SQL Server instance, it is easier and faster to use a Transact-SQL INSERT … SELECT statement to copy the data."

Comment: Even the demo code does not recommend "In the real world you would not use SqlBulkCopy to move data from one table to the other in the same database. This is for demonstration purposes only." in the comment. So, this is NOT RECOMMENDED way